# Update email_address_id, bean_id ,bean_module - Sugarcrm REST API

Tags: php, rest, sugarcrm

Im working on sugarcrm rest api to update a candidate email address. Firstly I'm updating in email_addresses table and then on email_addr_bean_rel table.

- For each table update, I'm creating session id and pass through api.
- On running the api, it updates the values in email_addresses table but not on email_addr_bean_rel table.

Whether i need to set any relationship??

Please help me to solve this issue...

```
//login --------------------------------------------- 
$login_parameters = array(
     "user_auth" => array(
          "user_name" => $username,
          "password" => md5($password),
          "version" => "1"
     ),
     "application_name" => "RestTest",
     "name_value_list" => array(),
);

$login_result = call("login", $login_parameters, $url);

//get session id
$session_id = $login_result->id;

 $set_entry_parametersEADDR = array(
     //session id
     "session" => $session_id,

     //The name of the module from which to retrieve records.
     "module_name" => "EmailAddresses",

     //Record attributes
     "name_value_list" => array(


    array('name' => 'email_address', 'value' => $_POST['emailid']), 
    array('name' => 'email_address_caps', 'value' => strtoupper($_POST['emailid'])),
    array('name' => 'invalid_email' , 'value' => 0),
    array('name' => 'opt_out', 'value' => 0), 
    array('name' => 'date_created' , 'value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
    array('name' => 'date_modified', 'value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')), 
    array('name' => 'deleted' , 'value' => 0),
     ),
);

$set_entry_resultEmailsAdd = call("set_entry", $set_entry_parametersEADDR, $url);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($set_entry_resultEmailsAdd);
echo "</pre>";




  //login --------------------------------------------- 
$login_parameters = array(
     "user_auth" => array(
          "user_name" => $username,
          "password" => md5($password),
          "version" => "1"
     ),
     "application_name" => "RestTest",
     "name_value_list" => array(),
);

$login_result = call("login", $login_parameters, $url);

//get session id
$session_id = $login_result->id;

 $set_entry_parametersEmailAddressBean = array(
     //session id
     "session" => $session_id,

     //The name of the module from which to retrieve records.
     "module_name" => "EmailAddresses",
      //Record attributes
     "name_value_list" => array(


    array('name' => 'email_address_id', 'value' => $set_entry_resultEmailsAdd->id), 
    array('name' => 'bean_id', 'value' =>  $set_entry_result->id),
    array('name' => 'bean_module' , 'value' => 'gaur_Candidates'),
    array('name' => 'primary_address', 'value' => 1), 
    array('name' => 'reply_to_address', 'value' => 0),
    array('name' => 'date_created' , 'value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
    array('name' => 'date_modified', 'value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')), 
    array('name' => 'deleted' , 'value' => 1),
        ),
);


$set_entry_resultEmailBean = call("set_entry", $set_entry_parametersEmailAddressBean, $url);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($set_entry_resultEmailBean);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you should be able to use the session ID between calls. No need to grab another one per call.

To set the email address for a custom module gaur_Candidates

Is the email field correctly set up in the gaur_Candidates module?

You should no be modifiying the email_address table directly. Instead you should use the built in email methods for sugar.

For any module with the email relationship

You can set the primary email address by setting the field **"email1"** (or email2, and so on until 5 I believe)

However I'm not sure if you can add the stock email relationship to a custom 
module.